# My scream becomes louder the faster I advance, though I do not have a mouth and will never in my circumstance

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *My scream becomes louder the faster I advance,*
>
> *Though I do not have a mouth and will never in my circumstance.*
>
> *The moment I depart is the moment I arrive,*
>
> *Though sometimes I delay, a situation I might contrive.*
>
> *A cigar is unnecessary for myself to blow smoke,*
>
> *And I did so for two centuries, until I was revoked.*
>
> *My pathways are similar to what is placed on enamel,*
>
> *Though instead mine are placed along stone and/or gravel.*
>
> *I will not reveal the purpose as to why I was created,*
>
> *Though you might guess what I am — the clues have been demonstrated.*

---

I made up this riddle for fun. Hope you enjoy!

Hints for the answer are below (extra long, as I have not made a riddle in days).

---

**Hint:**

> *One way, I travel on; one way, I travel in.*
>  *Either way, I travel on the steel of their skin.* 
>  
>  *My legs cannot run, but they can sure spin.* 
>  *Not carrying a ticket might prove to be a sin.*

---

**Edit:**

In the line, 
 `And I did so for two centuries, until I was revoked.` 
 this makes the answer different to what it was originally when I had written instead, 
 `And I did so for two centuries, until it was revoked.`

I accept both answers, but other answers are welcome too! 
 And thanks to [@MeaCulpaNay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38194/mea-culpa-nay) for the suggestion to the former line :)

Also, I changed the last sentence of the hint from 
 `Will you find me out, or just take it on the chin?`
 to what it is now, namely, 
 `Not carrying a ticket might prove to be a sin.` 
 
 I decided to change the last sentence to make it more "hint worthy" I suppose. However, to satisfy @MeaCulpaNay's answer below, I might have to change `ticket` to `token`. But, like I said before, I accept both answers (and others if there are).

*Later.* 
 Changed the third sentence of the hint from 
 `My legs cannot run, though they can sure spin.` 
 to what it is now, namely, 
 `My legs cannot run, but they can sure spin.` 
 for it sounds better.

Comment: "My scream becomes louder the faster I advance" - could be made into separate riddle. "some bombs were fitted with whistles on the fin to produce the noise after release"

Comment: $@$user477343 I'm very glad to see you've become an enthusiastic contributor here! I'd like to offer a couple notes on things I've seen in your riddles.  1) the "I made up this riddle for fun" line is superfluous; not really sure why you include it.  2) You supply a hint from the very beginning; generally, hints are added only if no progress on solving has been made, to get things going, rather than supplied up front. 3) Your "(+1)  ✓" comments on answers actually should NOT be done; your checkmark speaks for itself. ...

Comment: Finally, I'll note that your riddles tend to be somewhat straightforward descriptions of their subjects, and the added hint tends to be even more direct. I'd encourage you to read [What should we do about "riddles" that are pure trivia?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5160) - there's certainly nothing wrong with you setting easier and more accessible riddles, but it's worth mentioning that riddles are ideally more about *solving* clues than merely *recognizing* them. Making your riddles a bit more indirect needn't make them harder, but can make them better and more satisfying.

Comment: @Rubio ok, thank you. I will delete my "$(+1)\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$" comments. Also, I will try making my riddles harder, and honestly I have tried. I am no expert riddle-maker. I am just 14, and I like making riddles, so I do them. I won't add the hints anymore in the first turn, so thank you for telling me. But I usually add in the line "I made it up for fun" so others don't steal the riddle and call it their own. So, what do you suggest I do about that? Overall, thanks for what you said. I will find the link and work on my riddle-making.

Comment: If you want to keep people from stealing your riddles, don't post them :) —adding your tagline wouldn't prevent an unscrupulous person from stealing your content and calling it their own, unfortunately… jerks are going to be jerks. By sharing your content, you're putting a bit of faith in humanity. Fortunately, many of the folks here who appreciate your content and efforts are fellow content-creators themselves, and respect other creators' rights. As for your riddle-making, I'm no expert either — many of us are here to learn and improve, and I see your riddles getting better! Keep it up! :)

Comment: @downvoter may you please explain why you downvoted? Did I do something wrong or did you not like the riddle (because this might not be your taste)? I don't care about reputation — I just want to do what is right by the community :)

Comment: @Rubio $\diamondsuit$ I just want to say, thank you for moderating this site! My riddles have definitely improved (and I don't mean to say that in a selfish way). All I wanted to say was thanks; I hope you remain moderator for a while :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you a

> Train?

My scream becomes louder the faster I advance,

> It is very loud.

Though I do not have a mouth and will never in my circumstance.

> Trains scream but they don't have a mouth, and they never will.

The moment I depart is the moment I arrive,
Though sometimes I delay, a situation I might contrive.

> From the OP, they depart and arrive at the same time when coming and leaving a station.

A cigar is unnecessary for myself to blow smoke,

> They have smoke coming out of some of them.

And I did so for two centuries, until it was revoked.

> Changing to electric trains?

My pathways are similar to what is placed on enamel,

> Braces and tracks.

Though instead mine are placed along stone and/or gravel.

> Yep.

I will not reveal the purpose as to why I was created,

> I not sure, maybe it would have the puzzle to obvious.

Though you might guess what I am — the clues have been demonstrated.

> A Train!

**Hints**

One way, I travel on; one way, I travel in.
Either way, I travel on the steel of their skin.

> Train or subway. Also they ride on the railway.

My legs cannot run, though they can sure spin. 
Will you find out what I am, or just take it on the chin?

> Chugga chugga, is how they spin.

Comment: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Zngr, lbh ner tbbq. Va gur 4gu yvar, gurl qrcneg naq neevir orpnhfr jura gurl yrnir n fgngvba (be n qrfgvangvba, gb or zber oebnq), gurl ner urnqvat gbjneqf gur arkg. Nyfb, gur 6gu naq 9gu yvar jnf pbeerpg. Naq ynfgyl, va gur uvag lbh tbg gur "fhojnl" cneg pbeerpg, ohg gur bgure bar jnf "envyjnl."$]$

Comment: All fixed @user477343, Thanks for the riddle :D

Comment: i thought louder the faster it goes might be the doppler effect

Comment: @oMiKeY you can put that into an answer if you want, and I will upvote. As long as it fits all the details :)

Comment: **Train** does't fit perfectly "*And I did so for two centuries, until it was revoked*", trains still do run.

Comment: @Novice I guess that is the confusion. The matter of blowing smoke (or steam) was revoked. But if I changed the word "it" to "I", then the "proper" answer is below. But both answers fit the details perfectly with only so little minor changes, so I accept both answers.

Answer (score 7):

Well, already attempted and answered by Quantum Twinkle, here are my two cents:

> It is a steam engine

Most of the lines are already explained, but I prefer to differ at the line

> And I did so for two centuries, until *it* was revoked...( I guess it would be better, had it been.... until *I* was revoked)...As steam engines were operational during 19th and 20th centuries but not so in 21st.

Comment: I do not think a *steam* engine is the correct answer. You might want to read lines $5$-$6$ in my riddle. I only tell you about $20$ minutes after you posted this answer to give you time to explain your answer... you are on the right track, though, so $+1$ :)

Comment: Ha! Neat suggestion. Will do :))

Comment: This is the better answer in my opinion because of the "blowing smoke" part...

Comment: This answer fits better if you read "*And I did so for two centuries, until it was revoked*"